# You want me to go/leave?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Two people are having dinner at a restaurant. They have a heated argument and...

> A: Maybe you should just go somewhere else.

> B: You want me to go/leave?

In this context are "go" and "leave" equally natural?

Answer (score 2):

They are almost equally natural, with a possible variation in meaning, depending on the wider context of the discussion.

"leave" refers better to the situation when disappearing from the restaurant is the desired final outcome.

"go" might fit better if leaving is just a side effect, while the final outcome is getting (going) to a specific place.

For a generic discussion without other context, they have similar meaning.

---

If the simple "disappearance" from the restaurant is the desired outcome, then "go away" might be a better fit:

> B: So you just want me to go away?